# SetIntegrityCheck from DB Adapter in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-select

Hi there I want to use join in zend db select. I know that `setintegritycheck()` is importants in joins. I know how to implement it when I am having a model object like

```
$select = $this->select();
$select->setintegritycheck(false);
$select->from(array('info'),array())
            ->join(array('cfields'),'info.class=cfields.class_id',array('field_id','type_id'))
            ->where('info.id=2');
```

But In my case I am not in model. I am having `dbadapter`. Now I am writing my query like this

```
    $dbAdapter = MyManager::getDbAdapator('project');
    $select = $dbAdapter->select('info');

    $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
    $select->from(array('info'),array())
            ->join(array('cfields'),'info.class=cfields.class_id',array('field_id','type_id'))
            ->where('info.id=2');
```

The line

```
$dbAdapter = MyManager::getDbAdapator('project');
```

returns the adapter of project database, I have cerfied it. Now in this case my select object is from db adapter so when I try to get `setintegritycheck` it generates error

```
Unrecognized method 'setIntegrityCheck()'
```

Can I any body tell me how can I put integritycheck in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`setIntegrityCheck()` is a method on `Zend_Db_Table_Select`. If you are building a select from a DB adapter, you're using `Zend_Db_Select` instead, and there is no integrity check, so you don't need to worry about disabling it.

The integrity check checks that columns returned by the query match columns on the table, so it only makes sense in the context of `Zend_Db_Table`.